# DB2 : Find distinct from a comma separated values

Tags: sql, db2

Find distinct from a comma separated values in ANSI SQL. I am trying this on DB2 database.

Scenario

```
Id     Val
1      A,B,C
2      A,D,A,C,B
3      B,A,C,C,D
```

Expected output

```
Id     Val
1      A,B,C
2      A,D,C,B
3      B,A,C,D
```

Comment: Yuck.  Maybe just normalize your data before bringing it into DB2 and get rid of that CSV data.

Comment: I want the solution in SQL level only. Not on the re-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 offers a way to tokens strings using XML.  Using this, you can split the string into tokens and then use `listagg(distinct)`:

```
select v.id, listagg(distinct tokens.token, ',')
from (values (1, 'A,B,C'), (2, 'A,D,A,C,B'), (3, 'B,A,C,C,D')) v(id, val),
     xmltable('for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' passing v.val as "s"
              columns seq for ordinality, token varchar(20) path '.'
             ) tokens
group by v.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2be1f949382dd4ee1548cfcf3c48f101) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  I strongly recommend that you fix the data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is bad way to store data in any database.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your platform and version of Db2, you may have the functions SPLIT() and LISTAGG() available.

```
with dist as (
  select 
   distinct id, element
   from tbl, table(split(val,','))
)
select 
  id
  , listagg(element) within group (order by column_values)
     as disinct_list
from dist
group by id
;
```

**EDIT**
corrected name of the column returned by SPLIT(), IBM provided version is `ELEMENT` we happened to have an older User Defined version that used `COLUMN_VALUE`.

Comment: SPLIT is not supporting in DB2 version 11